# How to use third parameter of angular.foreach()

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to Angular . I understand Angular.foreach() method in general. However, i didn't understand the use of 3rd parameter of this function.

Below code prints [object Object],[object Object][object Object],[object Object] on the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html >    
<head> 
    <title>My first AngularJS code</title>    
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>    
    <body ng-app="" >  
            <script>
                angular.forEach([{ name: 'Todd', location: 'UK' },{ name: 'Todd', location: 'UK' }], function (value, prop, obj) {
                    var x = obj;
                    document.write(x);
                });
            </script>  

    </body>    
</html>
```

How to fix that code and prints the object to the browser? 
In addition, what is obj exactly, how can i use it?
In documentation it is said that :

Invokes the iterator function once for each item in obj collection, which can be either an object or an array. The iterator function is invoked with iterator(value, key, obj), where value is the value of an object property or an array element, key is the object property key or array element index and obj is the obj itself. Specifying a context for the function is optional.

Comment: This is merely a problem of your output method. Use `console.log(obj)` and look at your Javascript console; don't `document.write`, it's a poor debugging utility.

Answer (score 1):

Use JSON.stringify() to conver javascript object to string

```
angular.forEach([{ name: 'Todd', location: 'UK' },{ name: 'Todd', location: 'UK' }], function (value, prop, obj) {
                    var x = obj;
                    document.write(JSON.stringify(x));
                });
```